# I'm trying to display names on a table/calender, not sure if SQL Pivot will work

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT a.OCD, a.[f_name],a.[l_name],a.[ads_phone], b.wk1m, b.wk1t, b.wk1w, b.wk1r, b.wk1f, b.wk2m, b.wk2t, b.wk2w, b.wk2r, b.wk2f
FROM [dbo].[tbl_teleworkers] as a
inner join [dbo].[tbl_scheduled] as b ON  a.pin = b.pin
where ocd = '022'
```

here is my result:

```
OCD|f_name|l_name|ads_phone|wk1m|wk1t|wk1w|wk1r|wk1f|wk2m|wk2t|wk2w|wk2r|wk2f
022|John  |smith |111-1111 |M   |    |    | R  |    |    |    |    |    |
022|Jane  |smith |222-2222 |    |    |    | R  |    |    |    |  W |    |
022|Joe   |smith |333-3333 |M   |    |    |    |  F |    |    |    |    |
022|Jim   |smith |444-4444 |    | T  |    |    |    | M  |    |    |    |
022|Jill  |smith |555-5555 |M   |    | W  |    |    |    |    |    |  R |
```

Here is what I'm looking to get: So instead of the letters of the week, I'm trying to display all the Monday people show up on Monday stacked one on top of the other. Like so...

```
wk1m |wk1t |wk1w |wk1r |wk1f |wk2m |wk2t|wk2w  |wk2r |wk2f
John |Jim  |Jill |John |Joe  |Jim  |    |Jane  |Jill |
phone|phone|phone|phone|phone|phone|    |Phone |phone|
Joe  |     |     |Jane |     |     |    |      |     |
Phone|     |     |phone|     |     |    |      |     |
Jill |     |
Phone|     |
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
 SELECT 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY f_name ASC) AS Row, f_name,
        CASE    WHEN b.wk1m != '' then f_name + ' ' + l_name END as first,
        CASE    WHEN b.wk1t != '' then f_name + ' ' + l_name END as wk1t,
        CASE    WHEN b.wk1w != '' then f_name + ' ' + l_name END as wk1w,
        CASE    WHEN b.wk1r != '' then f_name + ' ' + l_name END as wk1r,
        CASE    WHEN b.wk1f != '' then f_name + ' ' + l_name  END as wk1f,
    CASE    WHEN b.wk2m != '' then f_name + ' ' + l_name  END as wk2m,
    CASE    WHEN b.wk2t != '' then f_name + ' ' + l_name  END as wk2t,
    CASE    WHEN b.wk2w != '' then f_name + ' ' + l_name  END as wk2w,
    CASE    WHEN b.wk2r != '' then f_name + ' ' + l_name  END as wk2r,
    CASE    WHEN b.wk2f != '' then f_name + ' ' + l_name  END as wk2f        
    FROM [dbo].[tbl_teleworkers] as a
    inner join [dbo].[tbl_scheduled] as b ON  a.pin = b.pin
    where ocd = '165'
) as S
PIVOT
(
MAX (row) FOR f_name in ([wk1m])
) as PivotTable;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!!

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Add `row_number()` to your result so you can use it to pivot the data.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and let me know if it works

```
SELECT 
wk1m = CASE WHEN ISNULL(b.wk1m,'')<>''
                THEN a.[f_name] 
            ELSE '' END, 
wk1t = CASE WHEN ISNULL(b.wk1t,'')<>''
                THEN a.[f_name] 
            ELSE '' END,
wk1w = CASE WHEN ISNULL(b.wk1w,'')<>''
                THEN a.[f_name] 
            ELSE '' END,
wk1r = CASE WHEN ISNULL(b.wk1r,'')<>''
                THEN a.[f_name] 
            ELSE '' END,
wk1f = CASE WHEN ISNULL(b.wk1f,'')<>''
                THEN a.[f_name] 
            ELSE '' END,
wk2m = CASE WHEN ISNULL(b.wk2m,'')<>''
                THEN a.[f_name] 
            ELSE '' END,
wk2t = CASE WHEN ISNULL(b.wk2t,'')<>''
                THEN a.[f_name] 
            ELSE '' END,
wk2w = CASE WHEN ISNULL(b.wk2w,'')<>''
                THEN a.[f_name] 
            ELSE '' END,
wk2r = CASE WHEN ISNULL(b.wk2r,'')<>''
                THEN a.[f_name] 
            ELSE '' END,
wk2f = CASE WHEN ISNULL(b.wk2f,'')<>''
                THEN a.[f_name] 
            ELSE '' END
FROM [dbo].[tbl_teleworkers] as a
      inner join [dbo].[tbl_scheduled] as b 
         ON  a.pin = b.pin
where ocd = '022'
```

Comment: Didn't work Jay. I'm still getting one name per row. Thanks though.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. Since I don't have something similar to your data. I was testing on my AdventureWorks2008R2 database. I will keep exploring and let you know if I found anything interesting. Thanks for the update.